# Failure obtaining db row lock

Tags: sql-server, quartz.net

My application has been working fine for the last 2 months. Last week number of users doubled so we started seeing this error in the log:

**"Failure obtaining db row lock: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."**

The issue resolves  it self when the number of user activity goes down.

The locks are happening because of these 2 queries:

> SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WITH (UPDLOCK,ROWLOCK) WHERE SCHED_NAME =
>   'QuartzScheduler' AND LOCK_NAME = @lockName
>
> (@lockName nvarchar(14))SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WITH
>   (UPDLOCK,ROWLOCK) WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzScheduler' AND LOCK_NAME =
>   @lockName

Things I tried:

1. I tried to restart the services but that didn't help.
2. I added an indexes to the quarts_trigger table but it didn't help.
3. I changed the database Cost Threshold for Parallelism to 50 and Max
   Degree of Parallelism to 4 and that didn't help.

System:
We are using Quartz 2.3.1
We have 2 quartz services in 2 different servers accessing one quartz database.
Triggers are being created from 3 different web applications.

Quartz Configuration:

> ```
> <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="QuartzScheduler" />
> <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="AUTO" />
> <add key="quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.type" value="Quartz.Server.Bootstrap.QuartzUnityJobFactory, Quartz.Server"/>
> <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
> <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="30" />
> <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="false" />
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="true" />
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="176400000" /> <!-- 49 hours -->
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
> <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="*****" />
> <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
> <add key="quartz.jobStore.acquireTriggersWithinLock" value="true" />
> <add key="quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount" value="10" />
> ```

Any ides?

Comment: What you now need to identify is (1) how long are you holding the locks, and (2) do the locks need to be held for that long? So, the obvious question: What are you doing with these queries?

Comment: These queries are generated by Quartz.net library. the lock is used to avoid multiple nodes acquiring the same trigger

Comment: I had just come to that conclusion myself (reading about Quartz online). How many users are currently being scheduled?

Comment: Honestly, it happens randomly. we saw the issue when we have 25k pending jobs and 100k pedning jobs